Converting an application to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in Entity Framework instead of System.Data.SqlClient
I've been trying to convert my application (which uses EF) from System.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to accommodate distributed transactions and I've hit a wall, specifically a dependency error.
We're working on a .NET 7 (we're upgrading to 8 soon) web application which is fairly complex, so we actually layer this library on top of our DBContexts to track changes. Since this application was also built on System.Data.SqlClient, I've checked out the source code and modified the dependencies to rely on Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, along with doing the same in our main application. I've also followed the Microsoft's instructions to use the new library as the provider. However, I'm getting the following error when I try to run the application:
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating MyApplication.Services.Implementations.UserService -> MyApplication.DAL.DataAccessors.MainContext.
 ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(MyApplication.ClaimsProvider.IClaimsProvider)' on type 'MainContext'.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key, Func`3 handleFailedLookup)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetServices(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetServices>b__0(Tuple`2 k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetServices(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<GetServices>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.OfTypeIterator[TResult](IEnumerable source)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.InternalConfiguration.Lock()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.<.ctor>b__10_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.InternalConfiguration.get_Instance()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration.get_DependencyResolver()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at TrackerEnabledDbContext.TrackerContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString) in F:\Dev\TrackerEnabledDBContext\TrackerEnabledDbContext\TrackerContext.cs:line 74
   at MyApplication.DAL.DataAccessors.MainContext..ctor(IClaimsProvider claimsProvider) in F:\Dev\MyApp\src\Data\MyApplication.DAL\DataAccessors\MainContext.cs:line 79
   at lambda_method73(Closure, Object[])
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.BoundConstructor.Instantiate()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.BoundConstructor.Instantiate()
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.<ConfigurePipeline>b__11_0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DisposalTrackingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ExecuteOperation(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method627(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

The providers I've swapped out in both the app.config and appsettings.json files:
configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.MicrosoftLocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.MicrosoftSqlProviderServices, Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

And of course, I installed the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer nuGet packages in both the app and the library.
I figured after excising System.Data.SqlClient entirely from the app and swapping out the providers, it would just work, but it's clearly looking for that file. I could probably just drop that file in a bin folder somewhere, but I'm worried it's looking for that file because it's going to use it to run all the SQL operations, which is exactly what I don't want happening.
EDIT: I missed a System.Data.SqlClient package in one of my projects. Removing it solved the issue.

You don't need SQL Server experts to look at this - so I have removed the tag.

I am a maintainer of the new EF6 provider. Please create an issue on GitHub and share a repro project (privately?) , and I will have a look. Assume it is missing configuration.
